# How do I center an h4 that includes both regular text and links, without losing the spaces between them?

Tags: html, css, centering

I have this `<h4>` tag:

```html
<h4>
    A <a href="https://openjdk.java.net/">Java</a> and <a href="https://kotl.in">Kotlin</a> coder.
</h4>
```

which has this CSS applied to it (inherited from `body`):

```css
body {
    font-family: jetbrains-mono;
    background-color: #444;
    color: #EEEEEE;
    font-size: 18px;
    max-width: 650px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto auto;
}
```

Here is the result:
[image: a picture of the website, with all of the items aligned to the left]

using just `align-content: center` yields the same result.

Problem is, if I use a flexbox to center the text instead of a grid, like this:

```css
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

this is what happens:[image]

How can I fix this?
the full html file is here: https://github.com/TheOnlyTails/theonlytails.com/blob/main/index.html
and the full css file is here: https://github.com/TheOnlyTails/theonlytails.com/blob/main/style.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to become a column you need the `flex-direction: column;` property. Add it to the container to which you added the `display: flex` property like so:

```css
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
```

I hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: It seems to be working, but now there's a lot more space between the lines.

Comment: Could you send a screenshot?

Comment: Since they are headings, you could decrease their margins in the CSS. By the way, I think they have the same spacing between them but it looks like they have more due to them being centered.